# Typescript Lodash _.mergeWith Unsafe return of an `any` typed value

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to merge a parent to a child object and ignore the nulls.
using lodash function

I'm Getting this Error :
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return: Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.

```js
const merged = _.mergeWith(child, parent, (a, b) =>
        _.isNull(b) ? a : b // Error on this line
      )
```

Currently I am solving it by doing

```js
const merged = _.mergeWith(child, parent, (a, b):any =>
        _.isNull(b) ? a : b // Error on this line
      )
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

The typing for `_.mergeWith` indicates that it supports [providing types via generics](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1813), and the return type is simply a union type of the generics. If no generics are provided, then it [falls back to `any`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/object.d.ts#L1851), which is the scenario you ended up having.

```js
const merged = _.mergeWith<typeof child, typeof parent>(child, parent, (a, b) => _.isNull(b) ? a : b);
```

If you know the type of `a` and `b`, you can provide them as such:

```js
const merged = _.mergeWith<ChildType, ParentType>(child, parent, (a, b) => _.isNull(b) ? a : b);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. a and b can be either number or string actually... so i'm not sure how can I type it. Also the error is occurring on the _.isNull line, just edited the question.
For now My temporary solution is `(a,b):any => _isNull(b) ? a:b)` it works but I'm not sure if this is the right way as well

Comment: To type a value that can be a number or a string use a 'union' type: `someValue: number | string`